# How to find a process that is sending HTTP HEAD requests

Tags: malware

When I was using fiddler for testing a web Client(capturing non-browser traffic only), it captured the below by coincidence. Is there any way that i can found out which process is doing this? I am on windows 7. I am concerned that this is a malware.

```
HEAD http://hmymtkwmm/ HTTP/1.1
Host: hmymtkwmm
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.75 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/1.0.219.50
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

with the response(not really)

```
HTTP/1.1 502 Fiddler - DNS Lookup Failed
Date: Fri, 02 Oct 2015 09:10:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Timestamp: 11:10:22.786

[Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "hmymtkwmm" failed. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No such host is known
```

Comment: Chromium-based browsers attempts to resolve 3 random hosts to detect whether these are being intercepted. See https://mikewest.org/2012/02/chrome-connects-to-three-random-domains-at-startup

Comment: thanks @Rob W turned out to be a Chromium based browser called Vivaldi causing the traffic. your Comment explained why it happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fiddler is installed on the same machine that is generating the traffic in question simply view the **Process** column. The number after the colon is the **PID**.

[image]

Launch the task manager and click **View** > **Select Columns**

Make sure **PID** and **Image Path Name** are checked.

[image]
[image]

You can now map the PID in fiddler to the PID in the Task Manager and see the dir path for that process.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use netstat -ano 
It will list all connections to a TCP/UDP ports on your machine and also the PID.
Check with one will match your proxy TCP address.

Then use process explorer from sys internals to confirm what the process is doing and get more detailed information.